# Controlling the Position of Floats (Images) in a Document / Images have the Wrong Position

Tags: floats, positioning

My LaTeX document just doesn't get the format I need. The images are floating all over the document, the `/pagebreak` and `newpage` seem to just ignore my order. I don't get what I'm doing wrong. Why it doesnt stick with what I'm writing?

here's my full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[width=160mm,heigh!=220mm]{geometry}



\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}


\begin{document}



\title{\Huge\textbf{Complexo Polidesportivo}\linebreak\linebreak\linebreak
  \Large\textbf{Relatório Projecto 1}\linebreak\linebreak
  \linebreak\linebreak
  \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{feup-logo.png}\linebreak\linebreak
  \linebreak\linebreak
  \Large{Mestrado Integrado em Engenharia Informática e Computação} \linebreak\linebreak
  \Large{Algoritmos e Estruturas de Dados}\linebreak
  }

  \author{\textbf{Grupo H - Complexo Polidesportivo}\\
  Luís Telmo Soares Costa -  080509089\\
  Alexandre Castro Ribeiro - up201205024\\
  José Miguel Ferreira Mendes - up201200647\\
  \linebreak\linebreak \\
  \\ Faculdade de Engenharia da Universidade do Porto \\ Rua Roberto Frias, s\/n, 4200-465 Porto, Portugal \linebreak\linebreak\linebreak
  \linebreak\linebreak\vspace{1cm}}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Introdução}


\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\textheigh!}{22cm}


\begin{small}
\onehalfspacing

No âmbito da Unidade Curricular Algoritmos e Estruturas de Dados foi-nos proposto o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação em C++ para a gestão de um Campeonato Polidesportivo. Na primeira parte do projecto foi requisitado pelos docentes que usassemos os conceitos aprendidos ao longo da primeira parte do semestre; o uso de classes e suas manipulações, herança e polimorfismo, excepções e algoritmos de pesquisa e ordenação. Na segunda parte do projecto, foi solicitada a implementação de componentes adicionais, nomeadamente, \textbf{estruturas de dados não lineares} - \textit{tabelas de dispersão, filas de prioridades e árvore binária de pesquisa(BST)}. Como tal, tivemos em conta todas estas componentes na construção do projecto tentando aliar as suas funcionalidades a um ambiente de uso agradável e intuitivo. 

\end{small}

\newpage

\section{Tema do Trabalho}

\begin{small}
\onehalfspacing
A aplicação de gestão de um \textbf{Complexo Polidesportivo} foi o tema escolhido pelo grupo para a realização deste projecto. O que levou à escolha deste tema foi o facto de ser um assunto com o qual todos os elementos estão familiarizados e também por ser um assunto abrangente, no qual teriamos um lote variado de factores que poderiamos ter em conta. 
Conforme foi sugerido pelos docentes da Unidade Curricular, as várias entidades do projecto foram divididas em \textbf{classes} e manipuladas a partir daí, com operações básicas de criar, ler, alterar e eliminar elementos. Demos, também, uso a excepções, muito úteis para situações de erro ou impossíveis. \textbf{Algoritmos de pesquisa e ordenação}, como o \textit{insertionSort} também foram implementados como uma ajuda na organização e estruturação dos dados. 
Estamos satisfeitos com a escolha do tema e com a diversidade que este apresenta. A nossa maior dificuldade foi em modelar e sintetizar todo o conteúdo que tínhamos e sabemos que com um pouco mais de método, seria possível realizar algo mais abrangente e completo. No entanto, conseguimos colocar em uso a maior parte dos conceitos aprendidos nas aulas e assim cimentar a aprendizagem.

\end{small}

\newpage

\section{Solução Implementada}

\begin{small}
\onehalfspacing
Tal como na primeira parte do projecto, a aplicação lê e trata convenientemente a informação contida nos \textit{.txt}. No desenvolvimento da segunda parte foram adicionados dois novos \textit{.txt} - \textbf{Adepto} e \textbf{Bilhete}. 
\end{small}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[scale = 0.7]{atletas.png}
\centering
\caption{\textit{Atletas.txt}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[scale = 0.7]{equipas.png}
\centering
\caption{\textit{Equipas.txt}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[scale = 0.7]{relatorio2/adeptos.png}
\centering
\caption{\textit{Adeptos.txt}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[scale = 0.7]{relatorio2/Bilhetes.png}
\centering
\caption{\textit{Bilhetes.txt}}
\end{figure}


\begin{small}
\onehalfspacing
A interacção com o utilizador é expressa através de um menu em que são apresentadas várias opções (são devidamente explicadas na secção 5 correspondente aos casos de utilização). 
No menu o utilizador pode navegar livremente entre os mais variados tópicos. O menu principal incide mais sobre as equipas, sendo possível criar, alterar, consultar ou remover uma equipa. Dado que as equipas é um aspecto inerente tanto a Atleta como ao Calendário(constituído por provas que por si, são constituídas por equipas e atletas), achamos que seria mais intuitivo colocar o menu nesta disposição. No projecto 2 é adicionada uma nova entrada ao menu principal - \textbf{Espaço Adepto}
\end{small}

\pagebreak


\section{Lista de Casos de Utilização}


\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[scale = 0.7]{menu.png}
\centering
\caption{\textit{Menu Inicial}}
\end{figure}
O(s) nosso(s) menu(s) apresentam um ambiente simples e agradável ao utilizador. De fácil navegação e perceptíveis, é possível realizar as seguintes operações:
\begin{enumerate}

\begin{small}
\onehalfspacing
\item Lista todas as equipas pré-existentes no projecto e as adiconadas durante a sua execução

\item Adiciona uma equipa.
\end{small}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{InsereEquipa1.png}
\centering
\caption{Inserir nome da nova equipa}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{InsereEquipa2.png}
\centering
\caption{Inserir país da nova equipa}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{InsereEquipa3.png}
\centering
\caption{Inserir patrocinador da nova equipa}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{small}
\onehalfspacing
\item Altera uma equipa pré-existente ou criada pelo utilizador
\end{small}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{AlteraEquipa1.png}
\centering
\caption{Inserir nome da equipa a alterar}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{AlteraEquipa2.png}
\centering
\caption{Escolher que opção alterar - \textit{nome}, \textit{país}, \textit{patrocinador}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{AlteraEquipa3.png}
\centering
\caption{Inserir o novo atributo que previamente foi escolhido para alteração}
\end{figure}

\begin{small}
\onehalfspacing
\item Consultar uma equipa. Encontrar uma equipa pelo nome e apresentar os atletas e suas informações.
\end{small}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{ConsultaEquipa1.png}
\centering
\caption{Consulta de uma equipa pelo seu nome e apresentação dos seus atletas}
\end{figure}

\begin{small}
\item Remover uma Equipa. 
\end{small}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{RemoveEquipa1.png}
\centering
\caption{Nome da equipa a eliminar}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{RemoveEquipa2.png}
\centering
\caption{Equipa eliminada}
\end{figure}

\begin{small}
\onehalfspacing
\item Menu Atletas. Este é o Menu onde se manipula a informação sobre os atletas. Este menu possui praticamente as mesmas funções que o menu equipas, apenas diferindo na quantidade de características alteráveis de cada atleta.
\end{small}


\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{MenuAtletas1.png}
\centering
\caption{Menu Atletas}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{ListagemAtletas1.png}
\centering
\caption{Listagem dos Atletas}
\end{figure}


\begin{small}
\onehalfspacing
\item Calendário. Neste menu é possível consultar agendadas para o campeonato, bem como adicionar, adicionar ou remover uma prova.
\end{small}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{MenuProvas1.png}
\centering
\caption{Menu Calendário}
\end{figure}

\end{enumerate}

\begin{small}
\onehalfspacing
Estes são os menus referentes à primeira parte do projecto. Como referido em cima, nesta segunda parte foi adicionado o menu \textbf{Espaço Adepto}. Neste menu é possível realizar-se a venda e compra de bilhetes por parte de um adepto. Para isso, foi implementado uma \textit{hash table} com todos os bilhetes. A cada bilhete está associado um Adepto pelo seu email, nome e clube preferido.  Os adeptos podem desejar associar aos seus bilhetes novas provas, ou trocar provas anteriormente associadas. É possível também que um adepto coloque o seu bilhete à venda, e caso seja comprado por outro um adepto que já tenha bilhete, as provas são somadas às do comprador; caso seja um novo comprador, este é adicionado à tabela. O adepto que vendeu o seu bilhete é retirado da tabela. 
\end{small}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{relatorio2/espacoAdepto.png}
\centering
\caption{Espaço Adepto Menu}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{relatorio2/CompraProva.png}
\centering
\caption{Escolher o Adepto interessado em comprar uma prova}
\end{figure}

\pagebreak
\newpage


\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{relatorio2/CompraProva.png}
\centering
\caption{Escolher a Prova que se pretende acrescentar ao seu bilhete}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{relatorio2/MostraBilhetes.png}
\centering
\caption{Todos os bilhetes pertencentes à tabela de bilhetes. Utilizadores sem bilhete(que vendem ou que não têm) não aparecem na tabela}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{relatorio2/MostraAdeptos.png}
\centering
\caption{Adeptos que pertencem à base de dados - \textit{Adeptos.txt}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{relatorio2/vendaBilhetes.png}
\centering
\caption{Menu referente à venda de Bilhetes - Inserção do ID do adepto que quer vender o seu bilhete. Após a venda este é retirado da tabela.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{relatorio2/ComprarBilhete.png}
\centering
\caption{Escolher o Adepto que quer comprar um bilhete.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{relatorio2/CompraBilhete3.png}
\centering
\caption{Escolher o bilhete que o adepto quer comprar. As provas do bilhete comprado são adicionadas ao bilhete de quem compra. O adepto que vende o bilhete é removido da tabela}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\section{Principais Dificuldades}

\begin{small}
\onehalfspacing
As principais dificuldades na realização da segunda parte deste projecto foi na adaptação do código previamente desenvolvido para as novas componentes inseridas. Demoramos também algum tempo a interiorizar o que nos era pedido, principalmente na parte das \textit{hash tables}, cujo enunciado pareceu-nos pouco claro. Recorremos aos professores, tiramos dúvidas e estamos satisfeitos com o produto final. 

\textbf{Nota:} O projecto ainda teve modificações ate à data de apresentação. Por brio, decidimos aprimorar certos aspectos que achamos importantes.
\end{small}

\pagebreak

\section{Esforço de cada elemento}

O trabalho foi dividido por cada elemento do grupo de forma equitativa. O aluno Luís Costa encarregou-se das Tabelas de dispersão, o aluno Alexandre Ribeiro das filas de prioridade e por fim, o aluno José Mendes encarregou-se da implementação das árvores de pesquisa binária. No entanto, existiu sempre grande cooperação por parte de cada elemento, que através do \textit{Github} se manteve atento a cada dificuldade e evolução.

\end{document}
```

[image: In this picture you can see that after that section I got a <code>/newpage</code> and still it stays there]

In this picture you can see that after that section I got a `/newpage` and still it stays there

Comment: You know, you don't HAVE to use \maketitle, and for anything fancy you are better off without it.

Comment: If you do not want something to move ***don't make it a float***. Floats are designed to float. It is a feature, but not always the feature you want. So don't use `figure`. If you need a caption, use `\captionof` from the **caption** or **capt-of** packages.

Comment: If you use **geometry**, do not make changes to the page layout which the package doesn't know about. In this case, you are repeating the settings you've already given the package, so it won't matter but doing it twice in different places and in different ways is a recipe for confusion and mysterious problems.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner There are better questions to link to than one specifically concerned with a class the OP does not seem to be using. And I notice that your answer here does not follow best practice recommendations, even though the answer you accepted there does. Of course, that answer is KOMA-specific, but there are equivalent strategies for standard classes which are better than the misleading markup involved in use of `H`.

Comment: @cfr - I think this document is a prime example of the "it's OK for the figures to float a bit, as long as they don't float too far away" case. I've provided an answer that uses the `placeins` package, which instructs LaTeX to prevent floats from being placed *beyond* the next `\section` instruction.

Comment: @cfr sorry, it was late and I just remembered that I had a question about floats in the past. I deleted the suggestion

Comment: @Perseverance Is your problem now solved with the two answers?

Comment: I took the liberty and changed the title. I hope you agree.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

- Do insert the instruction

  ```
  \usepackage[section]{placeins}
  ```

  in the preamble. That way, floats will not be placed after the start of the next `\section` instruction. This change will allow you to get rid of all `\newpage` and `\pagebreak` instructions -- the fewer "visual formatting" instructions your document contains, the better.
- If you need to further restrict how far `figure` environments may "float away" from where they occur in the input, e.g., if you wish to constrain the `figure` environments not to be placed beyond the next `\item` instruction, you could insert `\FloatBarrier` instructions before some, or all, `\item` instructions. (I'm afraid I don't understand Portuguese and hence can't tell whether such further fine-tuning may be useful and/ or desirable.)
- You should also get rid of most `\onehalfspacing`, `\begin{small}`, and `\end{small}` instructions. For sure, `\small` is a switch and doesn't take an argument. If you really need to limit the scope of `\small`, write `{\small ...}` (note the use of curly braces as delimiters).
- If you want the graphics in the `figure` environments to be centered, the instruction `\centering` has to come before `\includegraphics`.
- Be sure to leave one or more blank lines between paragraphs.

In the code below, I also provide suggestions for simplifying and streamlining the title page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove the "demo" option in the real document
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[width=160mm,height=220mm]{geometry}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}}

\usepackage[section]{placeins} % <- this is the most important change

\begin{document}

\title{{\Huge \textbf{Complexo Polidesportivo}}\\
  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  \textbf{Relatório Projecto 1}\\
  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{feup-logo.png}\\
  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  Mestrado Integrado em Engenharia Informática e Computação\\
  \vspace{1\baselineskip}
  Algoritmos e Estruturas de Dados\\
  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  }

  \author{\textbf{Grupo H - Complexo Polidesportivo}\\
  Luís Telmo Soares Costa -  080509089\\
  Alexandre Castro Ribeiro - up201205024\\
  José Miguel Ferreira Mendes - up201200647\\
  \linebreak\linebreak\\
  Faculdade de Engenharia da Universidade do Porto \\
  Rua Roberto Frias, s\/n, 4200-465 Porto, Portugal \\ 
  \vspace*{4\baselineskip}}

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}


\tableofcontents


\clearpage  % This is the only page break instruction you should need

\small
\onehalfspacing


\section{Introdução}


No âmbito da Unidade Curricular Algoritmos e Estruturas de Dados foi-nos proposto o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação em C++ para a gestão de um Campeonato Polidesportivo. Na primeira parte do projecto foi requisitado pelos docentes que usassemos os conceitos aprendidos ao longo da primeira parte do semestre; o uso de classes e suas manipulações, herança e polimorfismo, excepções e algoritmos de pesquisa e ordenação. Na segunda parte do projecto, foi solicitada a implementação de componentes adicionais, nomeadamente, \textbf{estruturas de dados não lineares} - \textit{tabelas de dispersão, filas de prioridades e árvore binária de pesquisa(BST)}. Como tal, tivemos em conta todas estas componentes na construção do projecto tentando aliar as suas funcionalidades a um ambiente de uso agradável e intuitivo.





\section{Tema do Trabalho}


A aplicação de gestão de um \textbf{Complexo Polidesportivo} foi o tema escolhido pelo grupo para a realização deste projecto. O que levou à escolha deste tema foi o facto de ser um assunto com o qual todos os elementos estão familiarizados e também por ser um assunto abrangente, no qual teriamos um lote variado de factores que poderiamos ter em conta.

Conforme foi sugerido pelos docentes da Unidade Curricular, as várias entidades do projecto foram divididas em \textbf{classes} e manipuladas a partir daí, com operações básicas de criar, ler, alterar e eliminar elementos. Demos, também, uso a excepções, muito úteis para situações de erro ou impossíveis. \textbf{Algoritmos de pesquisa e ordenação}, como o \textit{insertionSort} também foram implementados como uma ajuda na organização e estruturação dos dados.

Estamos satisfeitos com a escolha do tema e com a diversidade que este apresenta. A nossa maior dificuldade foi em modelar e sintetizar todo o conteúdo que tínhamos e sabemos que com um pouco mais de método, seria possível realizar algo mais abrangente e completo. No entanto, conseguimos colocar em uso a maior parte dos conceitos aprendidos nas aulas e assim cimentar a aprendizagem.





\section{Solução Implementada}


Tal como na primeira parte do projecto, a aplicação lê e trata convenientemente a informação contida nos \textit{.txt}. No desenvolvimento da segunda parte foram adicionados dois novos \textit{.txt} - \textbf{Adepto} e \textbf{Bilhete}.


\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.7]{atletas.png}
\caption{\textit{Atletas.txt}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.7]{equipas.png}
\caption{\textit{Equipas.txt}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.7]{relatorio2/adeptos.png}
\caption{\textit{Adeptos.txt}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.7]{relatorio2/Bilhetes.png}
\caption{\textit{Bilhetes.txt}}
\end{figure}



A interacção com o utilizador é expressa através de um menu em que são apresentadas várias opções (são devidamente explicadas na secção 5 correspondente aos casos de utilização).

No menu o utilizador pode navegar livremente entre os mais variados tópicos. O menu principal incide mais sobre as equipas, sendo possível criar, alterar, consultar ou remover uma equipa. Dado que as equipas é um aspecto inerente tanto a Atleta como ao Calendário(constituído por provas que por si, são constituídas por equipas e atletas), achamos que seria mais intuitivo colocar o menu nesta disposição. No projecto 2 é adicionada uma nova entrada ao menu principal - \textbf{Espaço Adepto}





\section{Lista de Casos de Utilização}


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.7]{menu.png}
\caption{\textit{Menu Inicial}}
\end{figure}

O(s) nosso(s) menu(s) apresentam um ambiente simples e agradável ao utilizador. De fácil navegação e perceptíveis, é possível realizar as seguintes operações:
\begin{enumerate}

\item Lista todas as equipas pré-existentes no projecto e as adiconadas durante a sua execução

\item Adiciona uma equipa.

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{InsereEquipa1.png}
\caption{Inserir nome da nova equipa}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{InsereEquipa2.png}
\caption{Inserir país da nova equipa}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{InsereEquipa3.png}
\caption{Inserir patrocinador da nova equipa}
\end{figure}




\item Altera uma equipa pré-existente ou criada pelo utilizador


\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{AlteraEquipa1.png}
\caption{Inserir nome da equipa a alterar}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{AlteraEquipa2.png}
\caption{Escolher que opção alterar - \textit{nome}, \textit{país}, \textit{patrocinador}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{AlteraEquipa3.png}
\caption{Inserir o novo atributo que previamente foi escolhido para alteração}
\end{figure}


\item Consultar uma equipa. Encontrar uma equipa pelo nome e apresentar os atletas e suas informações.


\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{ConsultaEquipa1.png}
\caption{Consulta de uma equipa pelo seu nome e apresentação dos seus atletas}
\end{figure}


\item Remover uma Equipa.


\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{RemoveEquipa1.png}
\caption{Nome da equipa a eliminar}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{RemoveEquipa2.png}
\caption{Equipa eliminada}
\end{figure}


\item Menu Atletas. Este é o Menu onde se manipula a informação sobre os atletas. Este menu possui praticamente as mesmas funções que o menu equipas, apenas diferindo na quantidade de características alteráveis de cada atleta.



\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{MenuAtletas1.png}
\caption{Menu Atletas}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{ListagemAtletas1.png}
\caption{Listagem dos Atletas}
\end{figure}


\item Calendário. Neste menu é possível consultar agendadas para o campeonato, bem como adicionar, adicionar ou remover uma prova.


\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{MenuProvas1.png}
\caption{Menu Calendário}
\end{figure}

\end{enumerate}


Estes são os menus referentes à primeira parte do projecto. Como referido em cima, nesta segunda parte foi adicionado o menu \textbf{Espaço Adepto}. Neste menu é possível realizar-se a venda e compra de bilhetes por parte de um adepto. Para isso, foi implementado uma \textit{hash table} com todos os bilhetes. A cada bilhete está associado um Adepto pelo seu email, nome e clube preferido.  Os adeptos podem desejar associar aos seus bilhetes novas provas, ou trocar provas anteriormente associadas. É possível também que um adepto coloque o seu bilhete à venda, e caso seja comprado por outro um adepto que já tenha bilhete, as provas são somadas às do comprador; caso seja um novo comprador, este é adicionado à tabela. O adepto que vendeu o seu bilhete é retirado da tabela.


\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{relatorio2/espacoAdepto.png}
\caption{Espaço Adepto Menu}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{relatorio2/CompraProva.png}
\caption{Escolher o Adepto interessado em comprar uma prova}
\end{figure}




\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{relatorio2/CompraProva.png}
\caption{Escolher a Prova que se pretende acrescentar ao seu bilhete}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{relatorio2/MostraBilhetes.png}
\caption{Todos os bilhetes pertencentes à tabela de bilhetes. Utilizadores sem bilhete(que vendem ou que não têm) não aparecem na tabela}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{relatorio2/MostraAdeptos.png}
\caption{Adeptos que pertencem à base de dados - \textit{Adeptos.txt}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{relatorio2/vendaBilhetes.png}
\caption{Menu referente à venda de Bilhetes - Inserção do ID do adepto que quer vender o seu bilhete. Após a venda este é retirado da tabela.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{relatorio2/ComprarBilhete.png}
\caption{Escolher o Adepto que quer comprar um bilhete.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{relatorio2/CompraBilhete3.png}
\caption{Escolher o bilhete que o adepto quer comprar. As provas do bilhete comprado são adicionadas ao bilhete de quem compra. O adepto que vende o bilhete é removido da tabela}
\end{figure}



\section{Principais Dificuldades}


As principais dificuldades na realização da segunda parte deste projecto foi na adaptação do código previamente desenvolvido para as novas componentes inseridas. Demoramos também algum tempo a interiorizar o que nos era pedido, principalmente na parte das \textit{hash tables}, cujo enunciado pareceu-nos pouco claro. Recorremos aos professores, tiramos dúvidas e estamos satisfeitos com o produto final.

\textbf{Nota:} O projecto ainda teve modificações ate à data de apresentação. Por brio, decidimos aprimorar certos aspectos que achamos importantes.




\section{Esforço de cada elemento}

O trabalho foi dividido por cada elemento do grupo de forma equitativa. O aluno Luís Costa encarregou-se das Tabelas de dispersão, o aluno Alexandre Ribeiro das filas de prioridade e por fim, o aluno José Mendes encarregou-se da implementação das árvores de pesquisa binária. No entanto, existiu sempre grande cooperação por parte de cada elemento, que através do \textit{Github} se manteve atento a cada dificuldade e evolução.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `float` package offers a float placement option called `H` (capital `H` in contrast to the standard small `h`). If you use `H` (meaning **H**ere and nowhere else) you can manually control the position of floats in the document. You could also say that they don't float anymore.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} % -> offers placement option H for HERE
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Example Section}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example Caption A}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Example Caption B}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should I delete my answer?